# Trying to fit a 4th order regression polynomial to a scatter plot but i get a strange result

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, data-science

I must use the sklearn module to perform this. I know numpy it's much easier. I have two single column variables, age and wage. I have broken them up into test and train sets. I'm simply trying to fit a 4th order regression polynomial to the data. I have

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import PolynomialFeatures
from sklearn.pipeline import make_pipeline
import numpy as np

polymodel = PolynomialFeatures(degree=4)

ageTrain_ = polymodel.fit_transform(ageTrain)
ageTest_ = polymodel.fit_transform(ageTest)

polymodel.fit(ageTrain, wageTrain)

model = LinearRegression()
model.fit(ageTrain_, wageTrain)
agePoly = model.predict(ageTest_)

pl.scatter(ageTrain,wageTrain,10, color='blue')
pl.xticks(np.arange(int(ageTrain.min()),int(ageTrain.max()), 3.0))
pl.plot(ageTest, agePoly, color='red', linewidth=2)
pl.show()
```

which gives me this (I removed the code which titles the axis). Any explanation or insight to what's happening and how to resolve it?

[image: Output]

I tried to add this to sort my entire age range and this is now my result

[image]

```
ageTest = ageTest.sort()
ageTrain = ageTrain.sort()

polymodel.fit(ageTrain, wageTrain)
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe that you should sort your ages first before making the predictions:

```py
ageTest.sort()
preds = model.predict(ageTest)
plt.plot(ageTest, preds)
```

Because your line goes back and forth instead of monotonically increase as age increases.

---

Not relevant to your question, but I think that in general, you should be careful with these lines:

```py
ageTrain_ = polymodel.fit_transform(ageTrain)
ageTest_ = polymodel.fit_transform(ageTest)
```

See, you *fit your model on the test data*. Instead, you could do:

```
ageTrain_ = polymodel.fit_transform(ageTrain)
ageTest_ = polymodel.transform(ageTest)
```

Probably in case of polynomial features it is not a big deal but with other transformations/models it could have a noticable effect.

Comment: I tried to sort it like you explained and received something which is still not right, I edit my post a bit. Also, I appreciate the advice in the second part of your answer. My new output still looks like it has a problem going back and forth. Unless, this is the correct Output?

Answer (score 1):

As @davforfu said, the strange result is due to the line being plotted back and forth as the data is not sorted. Another option instead of sorting is to use:

`pl.scatter(ageTest, agePoly, color='red')`

instead of:

`pl.plot(ageTest, agePoly, color='red', linewidth=2)`

Answer (score 1):

One way of doing this can be through Seaborn's [regplot](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.regplot.html).

```
import seaborn as sns
# assuming df is dataframe with data
df = df.sort_values('age')
ax = sns.regplot(x="age", y="wage", data=df, scatter_kws={"s": 80}, order=4)  
sns.despine()
```

For example, for dummy data

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

# train =  training set (dataframe)
# test = testing set (dataframe)

sns.regplot(x="Age", y="Wage", data=train, scatter_kws={"s": 80}, order=4, ci=None, truncate=False, ax=ax)
sns.regplot(x="Age", y="Wage", data=test, scatter_kws={"s": 80}, order=4, ci=None, truncate=False, ax=ax)

sns.despine()
ax.grid(False)
fig = plt.gcf()
plt.gca().legend(('train','test'))

ax.set_ylabel('Wage')
ax.set_xlabel('Age')
fig.suptitle('Age - Wage, Plots', fontsize=15, fontweight='bold')
plt.tight_layout()
fig.set_size_inches(10, 8)
```

[image: Age-Wage analysis]